# VS 2013 SqlBuildTask 04018 Error

Tags: visual-studio-2013, sql-server-data-tools

After updating to a recent service pack my Database project no longer builds.

I get the following error:

> Error    1   04018: The "SqlBuildTask" task failed unexpectedly.
>   System.MethodAccessException: Attempt by method
>   'Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.Build.SqlTaskHost.OnCreateCustomSchemaData(System.String,
>   System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2<System.String,System.String>)'
>   to access method
>   'Microsoft.Data.Tools.Components.Diagnostics.SqlTracer.ShouldTrace(System.Diagnostics.TraceEventType)'
>   failed.    at
>   Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.Build.SqlTaskHost.OnCreateCustomSchemaData(String
>   filePath, Dictionary`2 referenceMetadata)    at
>   Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.Build.SqlTaskHost.CreateCustomSchemaData(String
>   filePath, Dictionary`2 referenceMetadata)    at
>   Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Tasks.Sql.TaskHostLoader.ProcessReferences(TaskLoggingHelper
>   providedLogger, SqlTaskHost host, ErrorManager errors)    at
>   Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Tasks.Sql.TaskHostLoader.LoadImpl(ITaskHost
>   providedHost, TaskLoggingHelper providedLogger)    at
>   Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Tasks.Sql.TaskHostLoader.Load(ITaskHost
>   providedHost, TaskLoggingHelper providedLogger)    at
>   Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Tasks.Sql.SqlBuildTask.ExecuteLoadTaskHostStep()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Tasks.Sql.SqlBuildTask.ExecuteStep(Func`1
>   step)    at
>   Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Tasks.Sql.SqlBuildTask.Execute()    at
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.d__20.MoveNext() C:\Program
>   Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\SSDT\Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.SqlTasks.targets

I have tried rebooting and repairing VS2013
Thanks for any thoughts.

Comment: Duplicate Question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25505887/visual-studio-2013-database-project-msbuild-error) - you may like to keep your eye on it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to install the last version of SQL Server Data Tools
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/hh297027

Answer (score 1):

Just updating to the latest SSDT did not work for me.

#### My Config:

Win 7 Enterprise, VS Express 2013 v12.0.31101.00 Update 4, .NET 4.5.51209

#### My solution that worked:

1. Uninstall all prev versions of SQL Server, in my case 2005, 2005 Mobile 2008, Compact Editions, etc.  I left 2008 Setup Support Files.
2. Uninstall SSDT also
3. Download and install latest SQL Server Data Tools http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/hh297027 (as of 4/8/15 this is V 12.0.50318.0)
4. Reload project(s), clean, rebuild and no error!

Answer (score 0):

I had to do all of the above and a little extra.

1. Install the latest service pack for my version of SQL (2012)
2. Update SSDT
3. Remove old SSDT files in the new install location

   - See [Simon Mourier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/403671/simon-mourier)'s answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25505887/visual-studio-2013-database-project-msbuild-error)
4. Open project properties and uncheck "Enable extended transact-SQL verification for common objects"

   - Microsoft is [removing this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh272681(v=vs.103).aspx#bkmk_evf) from the next version of SSDT and VS

Answer (score 0):

Ok, solution that worked for me:

I compared dates and versions for files:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\SSDT\Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.UnitTesting.targets
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\SSDT\Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.SqlTasks.targets
```

and versions from my build machine were one year older than versions from my dev machine.
So I copied my dev machine files to build server, and it works...

MSBuild, seriously?

Comment: Oh... This is also mentioned here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28502360/4219011) as an answer to duplicate question.