# SqlBuildTask does not complete, gives no error whatsoever

Tags: visual-studio, build, msbuild, project

I'm having issues with a colleague of mine not being able to compile a Sql Server Database Project. The same project builds just fine on my machine. We both use [visual-studio-2013](/questions/tagged/visual-studio-2013), Update 3 (v12.0.30723.00) and Sql Server Data Tools v12.0.40706.0.

Looking at the detailed build log on my side, I see this:

```
Task "SqlBuildTask"
    Loading project references...
    Loading project files...
    Building the project model and resolving object interdependencies...
    Validating the project model...
```

On my colleague's side, however, it's this:

```
Task "SqlBuildTask"
    Creating a model to represent the project...
```

No errors are shown but the project still ends up not being built.

What could be wrong? Why isn't there at least a clue? Am I missing some kind of setting that causes MSBuild to fail?

Answer (score 1):

I see this question is a little old, but I ran into the exact same problem the last couple of days. A coworker created a couple of database projects in a solution we're working on, and they built for him but not on my machine. We both are working with SQL Server 2014 installed, Visual Studio 2013 Update 4. The project just said build failed, but gave no errors or clues as to why. I came across this other question on here:

[Visual Studio 2013: Database Project MSBuild error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25505887/visual-studio-2013-database-project-msbuild-error)

The information in that was helpful. I downloaded the ISO and reinstalled SSDT using this link:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/hh297027

That fixed the problem. The project builds for me now.