# How to debug a Visual Studio 2013 Extension Update page error?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, msbuild

I'm trying to open Product Updates in `Visual Studio 2013 / Extension and Updates / Updates / Product Updates` however whenever I open it it shows an error message with the following message:

*'=' is an unexpected token. The expected token is ';'. Line 124, position 93.*

Is there a way I can investigate this error, is there an editable configuration file or how to go about?

Most likely irrelevant but in case related I'm trying to update following the recommendation to the following issue [Visual Studio 2013: Database Project MSBuild error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25505887/visual-studio-2013-database-project-msbuild-error)

[image]

Comment: I just started receiving the same error. Looks like someone has submitted a ticket on connect: [Extensions and Updates: Cannot check for updates](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2937742)